# Javascript inidividual sprite fade out on canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, fade

So I have a basic canvas setting, where sprites are added a little above the canvas and fall down the page, before being removed if their Y position is greater than the height of the canvas. It's not an impressive creation.

It all works fine, but what I'd really like is for each unique sprite to also fade out as it moves down the page. From what I've seen, there's no simple way to go about this.

Modifying the global alpha of the canvas context isn't good enough, because this affects the whole canvas at once (as far as I've seen). I want to affect each sprite individually - so it'll start with an opacity of 255 and gradually decrease to 0 as it also moves down the page.

Altering the image data seems like a pretty hefty task, especially considering the position of the images are always changing (well, vertically, at least) and there can be up to 60 of these on the page at one time.

I know I could (if I really wanted to) create and remove HTML image tags and modify each images opacity via CSS, but this also doesn't seem very practical, again considering I can have up to 60 on the page at any one time.

Is there any way I can achieve this, even if it's one of the aforementioned techniques made a little more efficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) If you are only drawing those objects, you can just set the globalAlpha prior to any draw, like :

```
function drawSprite(x,y) {
   ctx.globalAlpha = 1 - (y/canvasHeight) ; 
   ctx.drawImage(mySprite, x, y);      
}
```

this way all draws are made with the right alpha.

(you have to define var canvasHeight=canvas.height earlier)

b) if you perform some other operations and you're not sure next operation will set the globalAlpha, just restore it to one after the draw (all other operations are supposed to use an alpha of 1 here ):

```
function drawSprite(x,y) {
   ctx.globalAlpha = 1 - (y/canvasHeight) ;
   ctx.drawImage(mySprite, x, y);      
   ctx.globalAlpha = 1 ;
}
```

c) another flavor might be to save/restore the globalAlpha by yourself :

```
function drawSprite(x,y) {
   var lastGlobalAlpha = ctx.globalAlpha ;
   ctx.globalAlpha = 1 - (y/canvasHeight) ;
   ctx.drawImage(mySprite, x, y);      
   ctx.globalAlpha = lastGlobalAlpha ;
}
```

this way you're sure drawSprite won't affect current globalAlpha, whatever its value.

d) Lastly you'll have to throw an eye at ctx.save() and ctx.restore() which allow you to perform local changes that won't affect other draws. Since, here, you only change globalAlpha, you'd better use a), b) or best : c), but i'll just write the code for the record :

```
function drawSprite(x,y) {
   ctx.save();
   ctx.globalAlpha = 1 - (y/canvasHeight) ;
   ctx.drawImage(mySprite, x, y);      
   ctx.restore();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this achieves exactly what I was after. I completely overlooked adding it into a separate function to my other canvas drawings. Not sure why! Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome ! i guess we all (including me) are too afraid to waste performance since javascript can prove slow. But here no way to get things done without changing globalAlpha at least once per sprite. Fastest would be, i just saw, to use a) way to batch draw all sprites, then set alpha to 1. But don't worry too much, on desktop things should be fast enough. Cheers !